# Global variable not not visible outside of if statement JS

Tags: javascript, global-variables

Struggling to understand why my global variables abundanceone & abunbancetwo will not show in the console outside of the if statements? I can see the values change depending on the if statement logic if I console.log inside the if statement however outside of the if nothing?  I should see an integer between 1-4 for each variable.

```js
$('#selector1').change(function() {
  var selector1 = $('#selector1').val()
  if (selector1 % 1 == 0) {
    if (!selector1) {
      $('#ValOne').val('');
      abundanceone = 0;
      console.log (abundanceone);
      return false;
    }
    if (selector1 == 0) {
      $('#ValOne').val('');
      $('#selector1').val('');
      abundanceone = 0;
       console.log (abundanceone);
      return false;
    }
    if (selector1 >= 1 && selector1 <= 9) {
      $('#ValOne').val(1);
      abundanceone = 1;
      return false;
    }
    if (selector1 >= 10 && selector1 <= 99) {
      $('#ValOne').val(2);
      abundanceone = 2;
       console.log (abundanceone);
      return false;
    }
    if (selector1 >= 100 && selector1 <= 999) {
      $('#ValOne').val(3);
      abundanceone = 3;
       console.log (abundanceone);
      return false;
    }
    if (selector1 >= 1000) {
      $('#ValOne').val(4);
      window.abundanceone = 4;
 
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    alert('Please only enter a whole number');
  }
      console.log (abundanceone +99);
        console.log (window.abundanceone +999999);
});

$('#selector2').change(function() {
  var selector2 = $('#selector2').val()
  if (selector2 % 1 == 0) {
    if (!selector2) {
      $('#Valtwo').val('');
      abundancetwo = 0;
      return false;
    }
    if (selector2 == 0) {
      $('#Valtwo').val('');
      $('#selector2').val('');
      abundancetwo = 0;
      return false;
    }
    if (selector2 >= 1 && selector2 <= 9) {
      $('#Valtwo').val(1);
      abundancetwo = 1;
      return false;
    }
    if (selector2 >= 10 && selector2 <= 99) {
      $('#Valtwo').val(2);
      abundancetwo = 2;
      return false;
    }
    if (selector2 >= 100 && selector2 <= 999) {
      $('#Valtwo').val(3);
      abundancetwo = 3;
      return false;
    }
    if (selector2 >= 1000) {
      $('#Valtwo').val(4);
      abundancetwo = 4;
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    alert('Please only enter a whole number');
  }
  console.log(abundancetwo);
});


alert(abundanceone + abundancetwo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="categorySelect1fromDB" id="ValOne" value="Abundance" class="DropChange" disabled>
<br>
<input maxlength="4" type="text" placeholder="Estimated Quantity" id="selector1" name="number_of_taxon1" />
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="categorySelect1fromDB" id="Valtwo" value="Abundance" class="DropChange" disabled>
<br>
<input maxlength="4" type="text" placeholder="Estimated Quantity" id="selector2" name="number_of_taxon1" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure right now why this would be the case (perhaps you have `abundanceone` defined elsewhere in your code?) but try referring to them as `window.abundanceone` instead. This should solve the issue.

Comment: From what you have posted, they are not global variables; they are local to `$('#selector1').change()` and `$('#selector2').change()`.

Comment: @PaulAbbott I was under the impression without the var it would auto drop into global?

Comment: [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns a string. And what is this `if(selector1 % 1 == 0)` for?

Comment: @Andreas  `if(selector1 % 1 == 0)` is to check whether a whole number

Comment: `selector1` is a string and not a number

Comment: You are always returning(return statement in each if) within each change so thats why you see nothing. It's no necessary to define return statements in each if statement in this case. So you can remove them and see some console logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explicitly declared your variables globally and it works.

Have a look.
https://jsfiddle.net/3tnzkmnc/

```
var abundanceone =0;
var abundancetwo =0;
```

In regards to the console log outside of the `if loop`, the code is never going to reach there as you have `return statements` within each `if condition`. The only time it will reach the console log outside of the `if loop`, is when it enters the `else condition code`, but at that point you are not setting your variables to see anything in the console log.

Answer (score 0):

`abundanceone`and `abuancetwo` are wrapped in functions so they are not defined until the function is called. Once these functions are called, you'll have global access to these variables or alternatively you can declare these variables outside of the `function`.